# MySQL Query Issue - Count Query Uses lot of CPU

Tags: mysql, count, cpu

We have a table on mysql to log all visitors of our site. The structure is shown below

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE  `tblvisitors` (
>       `visitorURL` longtext,
>       `visitorDatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>       `visitorIP` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>       `visitorID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>       `visitorUser` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>       `visitorShow` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
>       `visitorIPcaption` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>       `visitorIPRange` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
>       PRIMARY KEY (`visitorID`),
>       KEY `INDEXDT` (`visitorDatetime`),
>       KEY `INDEXIP` (`visitorIP`)
>     ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
> ```

The table has right now more than 5 million records.

We have an INSERT operation every half second and also a SELECT operation every half second which involves a CRITERIA on visitorURL column and Select of COUNT  field.

The query is :

> ```
>     SELECT COUNT(visitorURL) FROM tblVisitors 
>         WHERE visitorURL='http://mihirdarji.com/something'
> ```

This shoots up the CPU usage to 90% in an 8 core server with 8 GB Ram.

The MySQL admin shows lot of connection with above query waiting to be executed.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Explain plan says

```
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| 1 | SIMPLE | tblVIsitors | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 4293277 | Using where |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. first create an index on visitorURL
2. second only COUNT something static `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblVisitors WHERE visitorURL=...`

Comment: -visitorURL being longtext I am not sure if index will work
-will try with something static thing

Comment: you can definitely add index on longtext: "For indexes on BLOB and TEXT columns, you must specify an index prefix length" c.f. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems that enabling option [option_mysqld_low-priority-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_low-priority-updates) did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

rather than indexing the URL column, you could store a hash of the URL in a separate varchar column and index and query that.  But whatever you do, you'll need an index of the column you're counting.  Also look at the MyIsam keycache settings to ensure the indexes are handled as effectively as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any indexes defined in this table? If not, you should definitely [make an index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on the `visitorURL` column. Your current query requires full table scan and this takes a lot of time. However, indexing a long text string may give you the speed improvement you need if you use a simple index (because the number of unique strings is similar to record count in table). So, a full text index could be a better choice in this case. This will require you to use the special ["full-text search functions"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: full text thing is not allowing me to match exact urls, can I match somehow?

Comment: So the question is, what exactly are you storing in this `visitorURL` field? Is it HTTP referer or it is one of your sites? I'm just thinking, how many distinct values could be in that column

Comment: around 0.2 million distinct values

Comment: Then a simple index sounds reasonable in your case!

Answer (score 0):

Does visitorIp really need to be varchar(255) ?

Comment: Ah, I see now. You matched the length of the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

run explain on this [query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)

Comment: like other say , need create index on visitorURL , the 'possible_keys' is 'null' :
If this column is NULL, there are no relevant indexes. In this case, you may be able to improve the performance of your query by examining the WHERE clause to check whether it refers to some column or columns that would be suitable for indexing. If so, create an appropriate index and check the query with EXPLAIN again

Comment: thnx but will fulltext index help in this type of query